# How do you only order odd numbers in an int array and leave even numbers in their original position?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, there is this challenge online where you have to order the odd numbers in an array in ascending order, while also ignoring the even numbers. So for example, [3,1,4,2,3,6] would be -> [1,3,4,2,3,6]. I've written an algorithm to sort the numbers, but the output is wrong.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Kata {
    public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) {

        int n;
        int temp = 0;
        if (array.length < 2){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
            return array;
        }

        for (n = 1; n < array.length; n++) { // iterates through array
            if (array[n] % 2 != 0 && array[n] > array[n-1] && array[n-1] % 2 != 0){ // if n is odd and smaller than n-1 and n-1 is odd
                temp = array[n];
                array[n] = array[n-1];
                array[n-1] = temp;

            }
            else if (array[n] % 2 == 0 && array[n] < array[n-1]){
                array[n] = array[n];
            }
            else if (array[n] % 2 != 0 && array[n] > array[n-1]){
                array[n] = array[n];
            }

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        return array;

    }
}
```

Driver code

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Kata.sortArray(new int[]{3,1,11,2,9});
      
    }
}
```

for the array above, the output should be: [1,3,9,2,11] but instead it's [3, 11, 1, 2, 9]. I've been staring at this for ages and I'm stumped, honestly. Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: My first thought was to put the odd numbers in a separate array and sort this. Then use this sorted array to replace the odd numbers in the original array.

Comment: Shouldn't the order be 1, 3, 11, 2, 9?

Comment: For your code: you only sort if numbers at position n and n-1 are odd. What if there is a gap and you should compare positions n and n-2?

Comment: Similar to Ralf, but I'd use a second array to indirectly index the original array for odd numbers only. just an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an inner loop to find the next odd number to sort. And I used an additional outer loop because normally sorting needs two loops.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Kata {
public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) {
    int i;
    int n;
    int m;
    int temp = 0;
    if (array.length < 2) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        return array;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
            if (array[n] % 2 != 0) {
                for (m = n + 1; m < array.length; m++) {
                    if (array[m] % 2 != 0) {
                        if (array[n] > array[m]) {
                            temp = array[n];
                            array[n] = array[m];
                            array[m] = temp;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    return array;
}
}
```

Comment: wow man, this is the perfect solution, thanks a lot. I didn't realize you needed a second for loop for m